# Can Duhamel's Integral used for the following advection-diffusion equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

I have the following IBVP for advection-diffusion equation.

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{f(t)}{x} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$

where
$$T(x,t=0)=0$$

BCs.
$$T(x=0,t)=g(t)$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x,t)=0$$

Can Duhamel's integral be used to solve the problem if PDE has time dependent coefficient?

Comment: I think you can get integral representation for the solution using the evolution family associated to your system..

Comment: Can you please give more clarification? @S.Maths Maths

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the book of K-J. Engel and R. Nagel on semigroups:

> Chapter VI. Semigroups Everywhere, 9. Semigroups for Nonautonomous Cauchy Problems (by Roland Schnaubelt).

Comment: I have checked the chapter, however I find that the explained technique is valid for initial value problem (i.e. ODE with time derivative term). In this case, I have PDE which has also derivatives with respect to x. I am not sure if the technique explained in this chapter is valid for my problem @S. Maths .

Comment: The technique is general and covers PDEs. Just take $S(t)=T(\cdot, t)$ as a function of the variable $x$. This is rather classical for abstract Cauchy problems.